# Typescript error "Property '0' does not exist on type X" when using code generated graphql code

Tags: typescript, graphql, svelte, svelte-3

I'm having hard time understanding how to fix this typing error.

I have this code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { PlayerListQuery } from "queries";

  export let player: PlayerListQuery["playerList"]["edges"][0]["node"];
</script>
```

with `PlayerListQuery`:

```
export type PlayerListQuery = {
  __typename?: "Query";
  playerList: {
    __typename?: "PlayerConnection";
    edges?: Array<{
      __typename?: "PlayerEdge";
      cursor: any;
      node?: {
        __typename?: "Player";
        name?: string | null;
        age?: number | null;
        id: string;
      } | null;
    } | null> | null;
    pageInfo: {
      __typename?: "PageInfo";
      hasNextPage: boolean;
      hasPreviousPage: boolean;
      startCursor?: any | null;
      endCursor?: any | null;
    };
  };
};
```

the error is:

```
Property '0' does not exist on type '({ __typename?: "PlayerEdge" | undefined; cursor: any; node?: { __typename?: "Player" | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; ... more ...; } | null | undefined; } | null)[] | null | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

which is referring to `["edges"][0]["node"]`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The properties `edges` and `Array<[index]>` can be `null` or `undefined`, that's why you cannot access directly to their child properties.

What you can do to get the non-null values is to use the built-in type helper `NonNullable`. This will remove all the `undefined` and `null` types from the union and it will only leave the base types that can be indexed.

```
// Use in-between types
type ExistingEdges = NonNullable<PlayerListQuery["playerList"][
    'edges'
 ]>
type ExistingEdgeValues = NonNullable<ExistingEdges[0]>

export let player: ExistingEdgeValues['node'];

// Direct
let player2: NonNullable<NonNullable<PlayerListQuery["playerList"]['edges']>[0]>['node'];
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKAbAho4UAyAlgM4wCKArnonALxwDeAsAFBxwD6HSKAdlgFtgAfgBccAESVqEgNyt2YbLgIkY45m3aduyYPyFjJmHHgDCEXr2ABjGIUtyF24ABMA5sGJGAglCg4ADya2tpcPPqCIuISJioAoh7ATlqhNhRQxNDiWLyI8qnavBCu0YzOoezhegZlscp4KZVFUUakUIS87nAAPnC8FBgYBc3sWJ5GAwIARni9-YPDFZWEruLtne4jlQC%208wND2%20x7fQcYAHz7i0dwYOPAAJK8AGYQGstVunytMWj3T68mpUABZYYgAOVAMD%20nnE0wgEAwwFyN3YoOIaCgwAAbg4KBj7nCEUiUR84KQsLAzBkslAjLkaKdrmT9K5qZloPS8ldDssdtt%20axBSxWAB6UVwACqxFQnQAtLMYAB3YD6BB6YisCJweIgNSbRKeYh0ODgyzgxZYaZIwJxPBEUjSKCIADaEiUplUpAkAF0XcsAORuI0BhQ%2085avQ6vWkA1JABqWAwVGN9DNvAtQytNt1%20q6hq8LoADOHWKxQJBYHAkfAPSpxLnY-mE0mUy6A8VSgGfQVxaM4AA9YRllh9gAihCxdlYNduDSgACZxOnM9hrcBAivLevbfOHeQqM63XX7Wpfe3g15u%20di%20H253gN3exLKkPWEA)

Comment: Is there something less verbose?